# textbox value in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I just updated the StudentID and StudentName into the database.

I use these following codes to see value in the textbox but when i want to select the row it should be ID row not StudentID.

I mean i want to see value with StudentID, not ID row.

I don't want to use the ID row to see the StudentName.

I want to see StudentName when i enter StudentID.

```
sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Entry",sql);
dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[3]["StudentName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If studentID is primary key of table, then use:

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows.Find(studentID);
if (row != null)
    textBox1.Text = row["StudentName"].ToString();
```

Otherwise use `dt.Select` method.
Btw mixing data access code with UI code is not very good idea

UPDATE: also you can use LINQ

```
string name = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where row.Field<int>("StudentID") == studentID
              select row.Field<string>("StudenName"))
              .Single();
```

UPDATE: If you are entering student id and want to get student name, then you can just retrieve student name from database, passing parameter to sql command:

```
private string GetStudentName(int studentID)
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT StudentName FROM Entry WHERE StudentID = @studentID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = studentID;
        conn.Open();
        return (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Consider also returning only first entry (if StudentID is not PK) and verifying for DbNull.

UPDATE: If you need to retrieve several attributes of student, then I'd created class Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

And filled its properties from data reader:

```
private Student GetStudent(int studentID)
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE StudentID = @studentID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = studentID;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.Read())
             throw new Exception("Student not found");

        return new Student()
        {
            Id = (int)reader["StudentID"],
            Name = (string)reader["StudentName"],
            Grade = (string)reader["Grade"]
        };
    }
}
```

Then when you enter student id in text box, retrieve student from database and show its properties in controls:

```
int studentID = Int32.Parse(idTextBox.Text);
Student student = GetStudent(studentID);
nameTextBox.Text = student.Name;
gradeTextBox.Text = student.Grade;
```

Comment: It says the table doesn't have primary key but it has. btw DataRow row = dt.Rows.Find(studentID); what is studentid? is it the studentid column?

Comment: @aliprogrammer I don't know where you get studentID. This is `3` in your sample. If studentID is not PK, then use Select method `dt.Select("StudentID = " + studentID);`. Btw how do you get student id?

Comment: number 3 is the third row but not student id.

Comment: @aliprogrammer as I understand from your question - you want to get from datatable name of student by studentID. What are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: i have three column (ID which is identify column and has primary key) (StudentID) (StudentName) i want to when i entered student id it shows me studentname

Comment: Is StudentID the primary key in your database table that holds student record ?

Comment: no. studentid not primary key. ID is primary and identify column

Comment: these are the columns (ID) (StudenID) (StudentName) the identify column and primary key is (ID)

Comment: So how is the UI, do you want enter Student ID somewhere in a textbox and then expect another textbox to show name of that student

Comment: @aliprogrammer you can use select command with parameter to retrieve student name by id.

Comment: @Kunal yes Kunal. exactly. what should i do?

Comment: Select command should work for you. Just take the control.text property and pass it in the select expression

Comment: @Kunal Exactly, usage is like `nameTextBox.Text = GetStudentName(Int32.Parse(idTextBox.Text));`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thanks. Thank you so much. it worked. thanks. so if i have more columns like grade and ... i should use another private string for that?

Comment: @aliprogrammer see example with same query, but many fields of student returned from database, and data reader used to read these fields.

Comment: @aliprogrammer feel free to mark this answer as correct one :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i did. i should click on the mark, right? now the mark has green color.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Hey lazyberezovsky. i have a question but i don't why it can't let me post the question? would you please answer me question?

Comment: I have a table which has StudentID and StudentName. in my form i have a texbox. when i enter the StudentID it will show the StudentName.(AS YOU HELPED ME) but imagine if we don't know our StudentID. so i made a search button. when i click on this button it will show a new form so that i can search StudentID by typing StudentName. now the question is when i find my intention StudentID how can i show this StudentID by clicking on the cell.
i want to when i click on the cell it show the StudentID in the first form textbox.
thanks in advance

Comment: @aliprogrammer create property `StudentID` on your second form. If id is found, then set `DialogResult.OK` to your second form and provide value to StudentID property. On first form verify `if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` if its true, then read id `form2.StudentID`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky. can you answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455663/connection-server-name

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching to have a set of students, Show list of Names

and when you get the selection, get the ID of the selected Row...

you should use ComboBox/ListBox

1. set the DataSource to your DataTable
2. set ValueMember to  "rowID"
3. set DisplayMember = "StudentName"

now you have a list like

```
-Tomer Weinberg
-aliprogrammer
-some freek
```

and When you query   *myComboBox.SelectedValue*    you get the ID of that student
or NULL if none is selected.

**Edit**

[image: ScreenCapture]

put this inside a form with label and a listbox (can be combobox)

```
    private DataTable dataTable1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataTable1 = new DataTable("myTable");
        dataTable1.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
        dataTable1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(1, "Tomer");
        dataTable1.Rows.Add(2, "Ali");
        dataTable1.Rows.Add(3, "Some Other");

        listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedValueChanged);

        listBox1.DataSource = dataTable1; // collection of Rows
        listBox1.ValueMember = "id"; // what is the value of the row.
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "name"; // what should be visible to user
        listBox1.Refresh();
    }

    void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = string.Format("Selected: {0}", listBox1.SelectedValue);
    }
```

best of luck,

Comment: would you please give me the code you're talking about? please

Comment: I have a table which has StudentID and StudentName. in my form i have a texbox. when i enter the StudentID it will show the StudentName. but imagine if we don't know our StudentID. so i made a search button. when i click on this button it will show a new form so that i can search StudentID by typing StudentName. now the question is when i find my intention StudentID how can i show this StudentID by clicking on the cell. i want to when i click on the cell it show the StudentID in the first form textbox. thanks in advance

Comment: @aliprogrammer Oh, i answered a different thing...
this called a Dialog Box... i'll post an Example Simple Code in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Comments on my old post, this is a Dialog box  Example

```
public class MySearchForm
{
public string SelectedSID { get; private set;}
// code to show a list of Students and StudentsIDs.
}

public class myMainForm
{
    public void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        using(MySearchForm searchForm = new MySearchForm())
        {
            if(DialogResult.OK == searchForm.ShowDialog())
            {
                 mySutdentIDTextBox.Text = searchForm.SelectedSID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can customize the Dialog box using the Constructor and setting parameters before calling ShowDialog()

you can add more information to get from the dialog...

really, it is kind of like using  OpenFileDialog form.
to get a User Selected File

Good Luck, Enjoy.

Comment: btw can you answer me this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455663/connection-server-name

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DataTable.Select method. You can pass filter expressions in it. It returns the DataRow Array

```
DataRow [] rowCollection= dt.Select("StudentID=" + <From Some Control> or method argument)
```

**Here is the link**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

You can use the Select in this way :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID") ;
            dt.Columns.Add("StudentID");
            dt.Columns.Add("StudentName");

            object[] rowVals = new object[3];
            rowVals[0] = "1";
            rowVals[1] = "ST-1";
            rowVals[2] = "Kunal Uppal";

            dt.Rows.Add(rowVals);
            string studentID = "ST-1"; //this can come from a textbox.Text property
            DataRow[] collection= dt.Select("StudentID=" + "'" + studentID + "'");
            string studentName = Convert.ToString(collection[0]["StudentName"]);
```