# connection server name

Tags: c#, sql-server

i used "." as a server name when i wanted to add new connection into the winform. but i don't know why it's not working anymore. i should type the complete name like PC-PC.

when i use "." as a server name it won't show me list of database for connecting to them anymore.

now i have 2 questions

1- how can i fix it so that i can use "." as a server name

2- doesn't it have any problem if i use complete name instead of "." after making setup file and let the other computers for using this application

any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `.` server name in connection strings is an alias for the local machine. Did you develop an app on the same machine as the sql server is running and now you're having problems when the app is deployed to other machines?

In that case it is because when deployed to another machine, the `.` name refers to the local machine of the client. As soon as you want to use another machine than the same as the program is running on, you need to specify a name or IP address.

Comment: do you mean i should type complete server name like PC-PC\MYPC so that it can use on another computer?

Comment: `MYPC` should do - as long as the other machines can resolve that name. Try with `ping MYPC` in a command prompt. Also make sure you enabled the tcp/ip protocol on your sql server. It's disabled by default.

Comment: so when i make the setup file with the complete computer name when it has been installed on the other machine it will solve the name automatically? right?

Answer (score 1):

"." means the local machine. It only works if sql server lives on the same machine as your app. And you know what? 95 times out of 100 when that's true, you're doing something very wrong.

If it's a desktop app, you shouldn't be using a full sql server edition in the first place. You should be using an in-process engine, like Sql Server *Compact*, Sqlite, or even Access. If it's a web app or "enterprise" app, you should assume your customer will host sql server on a separate machine, and not on the local machine. Running sql server on the same machine as your app is almost never right.

Comment: i use full sql server. you mean it will encounter problems for desktop application?

Comment: @aliprogrammer It doesn't have to encounter problems, though deployment does tend to be more complicated. It's just that server engines are over complicated and not appropriate. Users especially don't want to have to install a server process that takes up resident memory and cpu time even when your app isn't running. An in-process database engine is a must better solution for this scenario.

Comment: thanks for helping me. finally will it encounter any problem if i use complete server name like PC-PC\MYPC after make setup file and let it install to other computers and use it?

Comment: Yes, that will cause a problem, because it's unlikely that you're "PC-PC" is going to the be the same across every installation.

Comment: It depends on how your app is put together. Personally, I'd be looking to re-write for Sql Server Compact Edition, but I don't know enough about your situation to make that a real recommendation.